# Overlapping tick marks in inset plot matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

In an older version of Matplotlib (with WinPython 3.4.2.3), if I wanted to include a subplot as an inset, it hid the tickmarks below it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeZam.png

In an upgraded version (with Winpython 3.4.3.2), it overlays both of the axis tick marks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8sCw.png

How do I revert to the old behavior, where the bottom plot's ticks are hidden?

Thanks!

Here is an overview of my plotting code:

```
fig=plt.figure(8, figsize=(8,7), dpi=300)

ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8], xscale='log', xlim=(5e-8, 1e-4), xlabel='...', ylabel='...',ylim=(-0.3,9)) # main axes
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.52, .52, .38,.38], xscale='log', xlim=(5e-8, 1e-4), xlabel='...', ylabel='...') # inset axes

# main figure
ax1.plot(...)

# insert
ax2.plot(...)

xticks = ax2.xaxis.get_major_ticks()
print(xticks)
xticks[5].label1.set_visible(False)
#xticks[-2].label1.set_visible(False)

yticks = ax2.yaxis.get_major_ticks()
print(yticks)
yticks[-1].label1.set_visible(False)


#start3, end3 = ax2.get_ylim()
ax2.yaxis.set_ticks([0,5,10])
```

Comment: What code do you use to inset the subplot? I don't have Windows, but I would expect `plt.xticks(visible=False)` while the inset was the current `Axes` to work.

Comment: I'm probably not doing this the best way, but I'm insetting it using the add_axes command and just manipulating the position argument to give what I want.

Comment: There's an `inset_axes` command and example: http://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/inset_locator_demo.html - does that work better?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have a lot to learn about plotting with matplotlib. I was hoping there was an easy fix so I could reuse my existing code without redoing it with inset, etc, but it looks like for now I'll revert to the older version because it behaves how I want.

Comment: I answered my own question. If I use the keyword axisbg='white' in ax2.plot() it works as expected.

Comment: Or `ax2.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)`.

Answer (score 0):

If I use the keyword axisbg='white' in ax2.plot() it works as expected.